# Remove all occurrences of a duplicate line

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, duplicates

If I want to remove lines where certain fields are duplicated then I use sort -u -k n,n.
But this keeps one occurrence.  If I want to remove all occurrences of the duplicate is there any quick bash or awk way to do this?

Eg I have:

```
1   apple   30
2   banana   21
3   apple   9
4   mango   2
```

I want:

```
2 banana   21
4 mango   2
```

I will presort and then use a hash in perl but for v. large files this is going to be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sort -k <your fields> | awk '{print $3, $1, $2}' | uniq -f2 -u | awk '{print $2, $3, $1}'` to remove all lines that are duplicated (without keeping any copies).  If you don't need the last field, change that first `awk` command to just `cut -f 1-5 -d ' '`, change the `-f2` in `uniq` to `-f1`, and remove the second `awk` command.

Comment: I don't think this works, uniq works in the same way as sort -u

Comment: Not with `uniq -u`; that does what you want, unlike `sort -u`.

Comment: Am I missing something?`$ sort ~/Desktop/fruit.txt | awk '{print $3, $1, $2}' | uniq -f1 -u | awk '{print $2, $3, $1}'
1 apple 30
2 banana 21
3 apple 9
4 mango 2
$ sort -k2,2 ~/Desktop/fruit.txt | awk '{print $3, $1, $2}' | uniq -f1 -u | awk '{print $2, $3, $1}'
1 apple 30
3 apple 9
2 banana 21
4 mango 2
`

Comment: The answer had a bug -- the `-f1` in `uniq` needed to be `-f2`.  I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This will keep your output in the same order as your input:

```
awk '{seen[$2]++; a[++count]=$0; key[count]=$2} END {for (i=1;i<=count;i++) if (seen[key[i]] == 1) print a[i]}' inputfile
```