# Remove all occurrences of duplicate lines in bash or Python and getting only and only the unique lines

Tags: python, bash, duplicates

I have already tried the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948111/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-duplicate-line) but it gives me an empty file, even though I have non-duplicated unique lines.

I have a large text file (2GB) containing very long strings in each line.

```
AB02819380213.   : (( 00 99   -   MO:ASKDJIO*U* HIUGHUHAHUHHA AUCCGTCTTCTTTTTTA FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
a01219f8b
NJSAJDH*)8888-   + 99 100.    -   NKJJABHASDGASGYUOISADIJIJA  TCTCTCTTTCTACACTAATCACAATACTACA FFFFFFFFFFF
a023129ab
NJSAJDH*)8888-   + 99 100.    -   NKJJABHASDGASGYUOISADIJIJA  TCTCTCTTTCTACACTAATCACAATACTACA FFFFFFFFFFF
000axa2381a
AB02819380213.   : (( 00 99   -   MO:ASKDJIO*U* HIUGHUHAHUHHA AUCCGTCTTCTTTTTTA FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

The expected output here would be

```
a01219f8b
a023129ab
000axa2381a
```

How can I do this in bash or Python?

Comment: Are you worried about the ordering of the lines?
In order to search for duplicates, you will need to first pass through the entire file to get the count and then print the lines for which the count is 1.

Comment: Yes, I want it to work regardless of where the occurrence is. In my original file the order is all over the place, one occurrence of a duplicate might be in the beginning of the file but its second occurrence can be right at the end of the file. The order of the output is not important at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried about the ordering of the output:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{for (i in a) if (a[i] == 1) print i}' file
000axa2381a
a01219f8b
a023129ab
```

Array `a` will hold the count of occurrence of each line. And in the end, print when the count is 1.

Comment: This works perfectly well and gives me the correct results very quickly on a 2GB file. Thank you!